# Can an Object have an access specifier?

Tags: c#, class, object, access-specifier

I'm new to Programming! Ignore if it a silly question.  But leave a comment.

Is it possible to declare an access specifier to object instances in C#?
OR is there any default specifiers for that ?

```
class Person
{
    public int age;
}

class Program
{
    static void Square(Person a, Person b) // Here note down "a" and "b" are instances
    {
        a.age = a.age * a.age;
        b.age = b.age * b.age;
        Console.WriteLine(a.age+" "+b.age);
    }
}
```

Comment: Default specifier for class members is `private'. But what do you mean by specifier for instance?

Comment: You have already declared one, `public`. See [Access Modifiers MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

Comment: Have a look at [MSDN description of C# access modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

Comment: Have a look at the MSDN Access Modifiers - C# Programming Guide (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx). Like in your source code without explicitly declaring it's "Internal is the default if no access modifier is specified."

Comment: The instances Person a and b are known only in the method you´re using them. Is this what you mean? However the caller of Square of course knows those objects as well

Comment: Ok all are saying the same thing except @AliSepehri.. I am asking this for reference type.

Comment: Access modifiers are only applicable to the types or type members.
You can't restrict access to an object *instance*. What *exactly* you're want to do?

Comment: I worked **Out** Keyword with types int and String, I'm trying can it be possible on objects Or Any reference type. @Dennis

Comment: @Sayse No, its not a duplicate.. Not just Access specifiers.

Comment: @Balaji: I'm trying to link your question with your comment. How access modifiers are related to `out` parameters? Yes, you can make `out` of any reference type, but what is that to access modifiers?

Comment: Its not related to Access Specifier, but i suddenly got stuck with this thought, Whether it is possible or not @Dennis

Answer (score 2):

The default for classes is internal, meaning, they can only be accessed by types in the same assembly. If a class is not contained inside other class it can also be public, in which case, it is accessible by any type. If it is declared inside other class, then it can also be protected, only accessible by the containing class or its subclasses, private, only accessible by the containing class, public, freely accessible or protected internal, meaning, accessible by the declaring class, its subclasses or types in the same assembly. The default for nested classes is private.
A member (property, field or event) can also be private (default), public, protected, internal or protected internal.

Comment: He doesn't talk about classes, but objects. Hard to understand, because those who have grasped the concept would never even think about this.

Comment: OP clearly distinguished types and their instances.

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate from a class, you can define its access scope by modifiers (This modifier is for type member(reference)).

> Modifiers are used to modify declarations of types and type members

Look at following examples:

1)

```
class Employee
{
    private Person person;  //private is modifier for person type member, not for Person class
}
```

2)

```
static void Square(Person a, Person b){...}   //The access scope for a and b is equal with method scope
```

---

For example this is not instance modifier:

```
public class Person
{...}
```

Comment: "private is modifier for instance" - `private` is modifier for type member, not for the particular instance of `Person`.

Comment: @Dennis: I changed my word, I wanted to use the word of questioner, but yeah that is better to say type member. Thank you :)